# I have no idea where my Ethereum went

Tags: mining

[image: i have no idea where my ethereum whent's??]

I sent this transaction to an investment page online the name: Zinc7, but the Ethereum that i send never made it to my account.

Comment: Hi Sajid. I'm not sure this technical site can help with a marketplace question. Reddit readers might know something about this company. https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/